# Get element in Instagram login page

Tags: android, vb4android

I cannot get element by id of instagram login page.(in Android)
This is my code, please see

```
Sub EditText1_TextChanged (Old As String, NEW As String)
    WebViewExtras1.executeJavascript(webview1,"document.getelementsByid('id_username')[0].value ='"&NEW&"';")
```